# Can't get Search to show in Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm new to Android development, and just going through the [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html).  For some reason the icons are not showing up on the action bar even though everything seems correct to me. If I press the menu button on my phone I get the menu items as text. However, I have a search icon that I want to display on the action bar but it doesn't show for some reason.  I have the following code:

OnCreateOptions

```
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.nina_main_activity_action, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
  }
```

Menu XML

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          android:orderInCategory="1"
          android:showAsAction="always" />
    <!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          android:orderInCategory="2"
          android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Manifest

```
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

Let me know if you need any further details, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `android:showAsAction="always"`use this `app:showAsAction="always"`for the search item.

Comment: are you importing the support libary or the actual android library for  the Actionbar??

Comment: How do I tell?  Sorry new to this.  Following every step in the tutorial, thought it'd just work...

Comment: @Ninstors check your imports are you importing the support library for actionbar